# problem with column oriented dbms features

Tags: database-design, performance, mariadb, dbms

I am currently looking for a free(or at least low cost) column oriented DBMS  with really good compression abilities (at least 10:1 ratio) and fast response time. Having evaluated multiple open source systems (monetDB, Infobright CE...) i couldn't find what i was looking for. I am wondering what is the best approach among :

1- adapting an open source system to my requirements (adding multi-threading or compression...)?

2- building a custom storage/query system from scratch

3- waiting for mariaDB column store (a new system based on an infiniDB fork) before making a decision

On a side note i wonder if the source code available on Github is that of infinDB community or entreprise edition ?

i am limited to one server with 32 GB RAM and around 200 GB of initial raw data, with that in mind i welcome any suggestions or alternatives